# How to change background color of a textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I just want to know how can I change the background colour of a textarea to a colour typed in a text box. I've managed to do the text colour, font and size, but doing the background the same way doesn't seem to work.
My code for the text colour and background is:

Script:

```
function setColor(where, Color)
    {
        if (where == "backgroundcolour")
          document.getElementById('textarea').style.backgroundColor = Color;
        if (where == "colourtext")
          document.getElementById('textarea').style.color = Color;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<p>
  Card color: <input type = "text"  name = "backgroundcolour" 
                           size = "10"
                           onchange = "setColor('backgroundcolour',
                                               this.value)">
  <br>
  Text color: <input type = "text"  name = "colourtext" 
                           size = "10"
                           onchange = "setColor('colourtext',
                                               this.value)">
  <br>
</p>
<textarea id = 'textarea' name="data" cols="100" rows="10">

</textarea>
```

it seems as though my internet was blocking the script so it wouldnt change the background

Comment: You should use jQuery to do it

Comment: What you have works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: @Carnotaurus there are a million and one reasons why a person may not want to use a library. If you could downvote comments, I would.

Comment: Ditto - How about document.getElementById('textarea').style would not work in every major browser? If you had tried it then you would know that. Hence, the jQuery comment. So why not just help the guy? Please give me one reason NOT to use jQuery. Any example would do. Thanks!

Comment: @Carnotaurus, agree with Chris, I can say wtf jquery, use mootools or extjs or whatever else. And btw maybe I don't wanna have additional kbs of scripts for simple things.

Comment: He objected to any scripting framework - if you want to ignore cross browser compatability issues then that's your choice. Happy code review; I'm off to eat.

Comment: @Carnotaurus: why does `document.getElementById('textarea').style` not work in every major browser?

Comment: This was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced: the OP stated in edit rev 4 that cause was: 'it seems as though my internet was blocking the script so it wouldnt change the background' (the script in the OP's question is not in error; it works fine).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working. Maybe you forgot to remove the focus from the text box in order to get the change event triggered.

```js
function setColor(where, Color)
    {
        if (where == "backgroundcolour")
          document.getElementById('textarea').style.backgroundColor = Color;
        if (where == "colourtext")
          document.getElementById('textarea').style.color = Color;
    }
```

```html
<p>
  Card color: <input type = "text"  name = "backgroundcolour" 
                           size = "10"
                           onchange = "setColor('backgroundcolour',
                                               this.value)">
  <br>
  Text color: <input type = "text"  name = "colourtext" 
                           size = "10"
                           onchange = "setColor('colourtext',
                                               this.value)">
  <br>
</p>
<textarea id = 'textarea' name="data" cols="100" rows="10">

</textarea>
```